# Can I use the following PowerShell command to check the port availability "netstat -ano | findstr 161"h

Tags: powershell

I am trying to check the availability on UDP port 389, 161 on a remote server. The Windows server version is 2012 R2.

```
netstat -ano | findstr 161
```

I expect the output such as "Port 161  listening".

Comment: Hi Daniel, this looks to be better placed on ServerFault, rather than StackOverflow.

Comment: Did you actually try running the command in PowerShell? Did something not work?

Comment: I tried it in powershell but the status of the port is not displayed .

Comment: Then the port is not open on the host where you're running `netstat`. Are you running the command on the remote system or on your local computer?

Comment: Tried both, same result!

Comment: Running it on the local computer won't do you any good anyway, b/c it's unlikely that your local computer has a service running that is listening on that port. If the command doesn't show a result on the remote host, then there is no service listening on the given port there either. Check the service configuration (is it actually supposed to be listening on that port?) and the service log.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Test-NetConnection cmdlet - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/test-netconnection?view=winserver2012r2-ps